# Software to use keyboard as a mouse

Tags: osx, mouse, keyboard

I am looking for a Mac OS software that lets me use my keyboard as a mouse (Something to emulate this keyboard's functionality: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rjnkHqnA3s)

I am aware of Mac OS mouse keys feature, but ideally, the software would let me configure the keys I want to use for up/down/left/right and left-click/right-click

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16564983 claims to have built something but hasn't publicly released anything.